# Converting the model to TFLite format get "Check failed: is_rnn_state_array "

Tags: tensorflow, android-things, tensorflow-lite

I want to convert to TFLite format

```
toco \--input_file=$TRAINING_DIR/retrained_graph.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/$TRAINING_DIR/${ARCHITECTURE}.tflite \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--input_arrays=input \
--output_arrays=final_result \ 
--input_shapes=1,224,224,3 \inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UNIT8 \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_values=128 \
--default_ranges_min=0 \
--quantize_weights=true \
--default_ranges_max=6
```

and it fails

```
 F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/quantize.cc:600] Check failed: is_rnn_state_array
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

TOCO currently doesn't support conversion of RNNs and LSTMs to TFLite. This is on our roadmap and these [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/tf_ops_compatibility.md) describe existing op support.

Comment: I am following these instructions
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2
and I don't get .tflite file just .lite and I need to import tflite for this project
https://github.com/androidthings/sample-tensorflow-imageclassifier
and if I use the lite file it crashes

Comment: @I.S. I believe they just used a different naming convention in the example. Your "lite" file is the "tflite" file. You could just rename it, so perhaps you have another issue.